# Choice correct reference on merge list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

I have Two lists

One that belongs to my updated Object, e.g. "ListUpdate", and another with items that are present at my database, e.g. "ListDatabase".

```
ListUpdate = {"AAC", "ABC", "UUU"}
ListDatabase = {"ABC", "ABD", "UUI"}
```

at this example I must have a final list with these elements:

```
ListFinal = {"AAC", "ABC", "UUU"}
```

But my `"ABC"` item must to be a reference to my ListDatabase item!

Here go my questions:

First I'm trying to do this because I'm using entity framework, and if I just persist the Item `"ABC"` from ListUpdate, it will duplicate my `"ABC"` item at database, like this:

```
ID - NAME
1  - ABC
5  - ABC
```

That's correct, if I just persist it will duplicate my item?

The second question is:
How can I get that final list using the reference to "ABC" present at database?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. Based to on what criteria you want to pick data from database? What kind of objects are ListUpdate and ListaDatabase: IList<T>, List<T>, IEnumerable<T> ??

Comment: If you have a requirement of uniqueness then put that constraint on the column.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this to remove all updated elements from ListDatabase

```
ListFinal=ListDatabase.RemoveAll(a => ListUpdate.Exists(w => w.Value == a.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm using EF 6, this method "RemoveAll" returns an int